# How to write send and receive web camera like two people conference in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I use code snippet from tutorial point .

The connection is always closed , i test it to send and receive itself in computer before test in two computers

It bind one port but receive bind the same port. If not bind the same port, it miss define the destination port for send side

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" type=
  "text/javascript">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
</script>

  <title>webpage</title>
  <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  body.c2 {background-color:black;text-align:center}
  div.c1 {position:absolute;}
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
</head>

<body class="c2">
  <div id="d4" class="c1">
    <p><input type="button" id="stop" onclick="stop()" /> Stop Cam <input type="button"
    id="start" onclick="start()" /> Start Cam <input type="button" id="run" onclick=
    "WebSocketTest()" /> Start Cam</p>
  </div><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function drawImge(){
    var video = document.querySelector("#video");
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#videoCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;


    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var faceArea = 300;
    var pX=canvas.width/2 - faceArea/2;
    var pY=canvas.height/2 - faceArea/2;

    ctx.rect(pX,pY,faceArea,faceArea);
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";    
    ctx.stroke();


    setTimeout(drawImge , 100);
  }
  var video = document.querySelector("#video");
  video.onplay = function() {
  setTimeout(drawImge , 300);
  };

   var stop = function () {
      var stream = video.srcObject;
      var tracks = stream.getTracks();
      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        var track = tracks[i];
        track.stop();
      }
      video.srcObject = null;
    }
    var start = function () {
      var video = document.getElementById('video'),
        vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
          .then(function (stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;

            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
               
               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:123/echo");
               var wss = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80/echo");
               wss.onopen = function() {
                  
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  wss.send(stream);
                  
               };
               wss.onmessage = function (evt) {
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  
               };
               wss.onclose = function() {
                  
                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed...");
               };
            } else {
              
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }

          }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!");
          });
      }
    }
    $(function () {
      start();
    });



    var WebSocketTest = function () {
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
               
               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:123/echo");

               ws.onopen = function() {
                  
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };
               ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };
               ws.onclose = function() {                   
                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed...");
               };
            } else {
              
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
    }
    $(function () {
      WebSocketTest();
    });

  //]]>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried port 123 and 80 and 10000, though gpedit IP security allow port 80, 123, 10000
But always said connection closed

Answer (score 1):

You can use WEB RTC
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API

here you can find nice tutorial for beginners:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4